# Set ImageAnnoation image using embedded Resources instead of a file name

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

I'm using the Chart control from the DataVisualization library, and want to use image annotations on my chart.  The problem is that the `ImageAnnotation.Image` property is a path to the image, and there doesn't appear to be an exposed `Bitmap` property that I could use to load the image from the Resources object like I can for any other .net control.

Is there anyway I'm overlooking to load this using embedded resources instead of reading a separate file off the disk?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer.  You need to add the image to the parent Chart's `NamedImage` collection.

```
private string imageName = "myImage";

//in constructor
NamedImage namedImage = new NamedImage(imageName, Properties.Resources.myImage);
mChart.Images.Add(namedImage);

//where creating the annotation
ImageAnnotation imageAnnotation = new ImageAnnotation();
imageAnnotation.Image = imageName;
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer Dan, I'm looking into the same issue and found your solution.  I will be trying this out :D

Comment: Thank you for pointing this. Much more quicker than having to parse hundreds pages of docs or trying to guess this thing which is not obvious at all.

Comment: Note that in VS2013, mChart.Images does not appear in Intellisense.  However, the property still exists.